# Question about executing a while loop in C#

Tags: c#, error-handling, while-loop

So I have this code where you enter your "area code" and then you enter how long you would like the call to be. This is basically a simple calculator that would find the cost of how much a call would be depending on your area code. I am having trouble trying to figure out how to keep the loop running if I enter in an invalid area code. As of now if I enter in an invalid area code the entire program will just end in the command prompt. Heres the code:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace Chapter6._1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // array info //
            int[] phoneAreacode = { 608, 414, 262, 815, 715, 920 };
            double[] phoneCost = { .05, .10, .07, .24, .16, .14 };
            // declaring variables //
            int x;
            int areaCode;
            double cost = 0;
            int callLength;
            bool validAreacode = false;
            // start of actual code //
            Write("Enter in the area code you want to call: ");
            areaCode = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
            x = 0;
            while (x < phoneAreacode.Length && areaCode != phoneAreacode[x])
                ++x;
            if(x != phoneAreacode.Length)
            {
                validAreacode = true;
                cost = phoneCost[x];
            }
            if (validAreacode)
            {
                Write("Enter in the length of your call: ");
                callLength = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
                double finalCost = callLength * cost;
                WriteLine("Your call to area code " + areaCode + " for " + callLength + " minutes will cost " + finalCost.ToString("C"));
            }
            else
            {
                WriteLine("YOU MUST ENTER A VALID AREA CODE!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will get screamed at for this but just use a label `myLabel:` before `Enter in the area code`. Then after "You must enter a valid..." use `goto myLabel`

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `do-While` here:

Basically when you do `do-while` you force the code on the `do` to be done until the condition in the `while` is completed. in your case, you need to add the checking of the pohne number inside the `do` statement, and to know if the person selected a correct value, you can do `Array.FindIndex()`:
this will be your `do-while` loop, also i chaned your `x` for `index` try to use names for the variables that have some meaning. (index is not perfect anyway)

```
do
{
    Write("Enter in the area code you want to call: ");
    areaCode = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

    index = Array.FindIndex(phoneAreacode, w => w == areaCode);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        validAreacode = true;
    }
    else
    {
        WriteLine("YOU MUST ENTER A VALID AREA CODE!");
    }

} while (!validAreacode);
```

and this will be your entire main method:

```
int[] phoneAreacode = { 608, 414, 262, 815, 715, 920 };
double[] phoneCost = { .05, .10, .07, .24, .16, .14 };
// declaring variables //
int index;
int areaCode;
int callLength;
bool validAreacode = false;
// start of actual code //



do
{
    Write("Enter in the area code you want to call: ");
    areaCode = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

    index = Array.FindIndex(phoneAreacode, w => w == areaCode);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        validAreacode = true;
    }
    else
    {
        WriteLine("YOU MUST ENTER A VALID AREA CODE!");
    }

} while (!validAreacode);


Write("Enter in the length of your call: ");
callLength = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
double finalCost = callLength * phoneCost[index];
WriteLine("Your call to area code " + areaCode + " for " + callLength + " minutes will cost " + finalCost.ToString("C"));
```

As you can see you can also remove the `while` you have to loop the array and the `if-else` for the valid codes. assuming that when the code reach that point, the area is correct.

It's a good practice to try to remove the number of `if-else`.

Answer (score 1):

You might wrap your Read and Check routine into another while-loop:

```
bool validAreacode = false;

while(!validAreacode)
{
    // start of actual code //
    Write("Enter in the area code you want to call: ");
    areaCode = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
    x = 0;
    while (x < phoneAreacode.Length && areaCode != phoneAreacode[x])
        ++x;
    if(x != phoneAreacode.Length)
    {
        validAreacode = true;
        cost = phoneCost[x];
    }
    else
    {
        WriteLine("YOU MUST ENTER A VALID AREA CODE!");
    }
}
```

This is the simplest solution for you (not so much changes in your code required). But your code still has the problems. Your program will be crashed if user tries to print any not digit character instead of area code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to loop the entire code section, something like this

```
while (true)
{

  Write("Enter in the area code you want to call: ");

  var input = ReadLine();

  if (input == "Exit")
      break;

  areaCode = Convert.ToInt32(input);
  x = 0;

while (x < phoneAreacode.Length && areaCode != phoneAreacode[x])
       ++x;      

  if(x != phoneAreacode.Length)
  {
       validAreacode = true;
        cost = phoneCost[x];
   }
  else if (validAreacode)
  {
      Write("Enter in the length of your call: ");
      callLength = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
      double finalCost = callLength * cost;
      WriteLine("Your call to area code " + areaCode + " for " + callLength + " minutes will cost " + finalCost.ToString("C"));
  }
  else
  {
      WriteLine("YOU MUST ENTER A VALID AREA CODE!");
   }

}
```

Don't forget to add a check for when user types something that's not a digit